# How do I split an atom in Parslet?

Tags: ruby, arrays, parsing, parslet

I'm building an SQL-like query language. I would like to be able to handle lists of items delimited by commas. I have successfully achieved this with this code:

```
class QueryParser < Parslet::Parser
  rule(:space) { match('\s').repeat(1) }
  rule(:space?) { space.maybe }

  rule(:delimiter) { space? >> str(',') >> space? }

  rule(:select) { str('SELECT') >> space? }
  rule(:select_value) { str('*') | match('[a-zA-Z]').repeat(1) }
  rule(:select_arguments) do
    space? >>
    (select_value >> (delimiter >> select_value).repeat).maybe.as(:select) >>
    space?
  end

  rule(:from) { str('FROM') >> space? }
  rule(:from_arguments) { match('[a-zA-Z]').repeat(1).as(:from) >> space? }

  rule(:query) { select >> select_arguments >> from >> from_arguments }
  root(:query)
end
```

Where something like `SELECT id,name,fork FROM forks` correctly outputs the `{:select=>"id,name,fork"@7, :from=>"forks"@25}` tree.

Now, instead of messing around with this later, I would like to be able to convert the `SELECT` arguments (`id,name,fork` in this case) into an Array. I can do this by running `'id,name,fork'.split ','`. I cannot get the Parslet transformer to do this for me when applied. This my code for my query transformer:

```
class QueryTransformer < Parslet::Transform
  rule(select: simple(:args)) { args.split(',') }
end
```

When applied like so:

```
QueryTransformer.new.apply(
  QueryParser.new.parse('SELECT id,name,fork FROM forks')
)
```

The result is the same as when I didn't apply it: `{:select=>"id,name,fork"@7, :from=>"forks"@25}`.

The value I was hoping `:select` to be is an Array like this `["id","name","fork"]`.

**My question is:** how do I split the value of `:select` into an Array using transformers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put "as(:xxx)" on whatever part of the parse tree you want to be able to play with later.

Here I changed your `rule(:select_value)` to remember the values *as* a `:value`

```
rule(:select_value) { (str('*') | match('[a-zA-Z]').repeat(1)).as(:value) }
```

Now your parser outputs :

```
{:select=>[{:value=>"id"@7}, {:value=>"name"@10}, {:value=>"fork"@15}], :from=>"forks"@25}
```

Which is easy to transform using:

```
class QueryTransformer < Parslet::Transform
  rule(:value => simple(:val)) { val }
end
```

Then you get:

```
{:select=>["id"@7, "name"@10, "fork"@15], :from=>"forks"@25}
```

So in full the code is as follows :-

```
require 'parslet'


class QueryParser < Parslet::Parser
  rule(:space) { match('\s').repeat(1) }
  rule(:space?) { space.maybe }

  rule(:delimiter) { space? >> str(',') >> space? }

  rule(:select) { str('SELECT') >> space? }

  rule(:select_value) { (str('*') | match('[a-zA-Z]').repeat(1)).as(:value) }

  rule(:select_arguments) do
    space? >>
    (select_value >> (delimiter >> select_value).repeat).maybe.as(:select) >>
    space?
  end

  rule(:from) { str('FROM') >> space? }
  rule(:from_arguments) { match('[a-zA-Z]').repeat(1).as(:from) >> space? }

  rule(:query) { select >> select_arguments >> from >> from_arguments }
  root(:query)
end

puts QueryParser.new.parse('SELECT id,name,fork FROM forks') 
# =>  {:select=>[{:value=>"id"@7}, {:value=>"name"@10}, {:value=>"fork"@15}], :from=>"forks"@25}

class QueryTransformer < Parslet::Transform
  rule(:value => simple(:val)) { val }
end

puts QueryTransformer.new.apply(
  QueryParser.new.parse('SELECT id,name,fork FROM forks')
)
# => {:select=>["id"@7, "name"@10, "fork"@15], :from=>"forks"@25}
```